# Titanium Accesibility order issue

Tags: javascript, android, ios, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I want the Accessibility Inspector on iOS or Talk-back on Android to read some views in a certain way.

I read the appcelerator docs and couldnt find a way to do it.
http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Accessibility

Is there a way to group views for Accessibility on Titanium similar to the way iOS do it?

```
-(BOOL)shouldGroupAccessibilityChildren{
return YES;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default views are available for accessibility services. If you want to skip views, then use the [accessibilityHidden](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.View-property-accessibilityHidden) property.